# Проверка массива окружностей на пересечение

Tags: java, геометрия

Есть массив окружностей(класс), у него есть координаты центра и радиус, которые заполняются рандомом. Как организовать проверку массива на пересечение окружностей друг с другом?
Файл Main.java:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Circle> array = new ArrayList<>(10);
    int[] coordinatesX = {50, 100, 300, 500, 700, 900};
    int[] coordinatesY = {50, 100, 300, 500, 700};
    int[] r = {50, 100, 120, 150, 200};

    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        Circle c = new Circle(coordinatesX[rnd.nextInt(6)],         
        coordinatesY[rnd.nextInt(6)], r[rnd.nextInt(5)]);
    }
}
}
```

Файл Circle.java:

```
package com.company;

public class Circle {
private int x;
private int y;
private int r;
Circle(int x,int y,int r){
    this.x =x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Когда две окружности пересекаются?

Когда **расстояние между центрами меньше суммы радиусов**.

Кроме того, это расстояние должно быть больше модуля разности радиусов, если случай полного нахождения одной окружности в другой не считается за пересечение.

Вот и используйте эти свойства.

Answer (score 1):

Как написал [MBo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/291659/mbo), окружности пересекаются, если расстояние между центрами меньше суммы радиусов.

Найти расстояние можно по формуле `A = √(X²+Y²) = √ ((X2-X1)²+(Y2-Y1)²)`.

Добавьте геттеры в класс `Circle`:

```
//и такой же геттер для y и r
public int getX() {
   return x; 
}
```

Теперь берем два круга(объекты `Circle`, `c1` и `c2`), и находим расстояние между ними:

```
int distance = Math.sqrt( Math.sqr(c2.getX() - c1.getX()) + Math.sqr(c2.getY() - c1.getY()) );
```

Находим, действительно ли расстояние больше чем сумма радиусов:

```
if(distanse < c1.getR() + c2.getR())//сравниваем расстояние с суммой радиусов
   System.out.println("Один круг пересекает другой круг")
else
   System.out.println("Круги не пересекаются")
```

P.S. Вы там создаете `c` в цикле `for`, и `c` у вас существует только в цикле `for`.